# How to use ui5-cli to launch my UI5 project with the URL "localhost:8080/#" without the "index.html"?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have followed the [walkthrough](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/2680aa9b16c14a00b01261d04babbb39) document to create my first SAPUI5 / OpenUI5 project. And I use [`ui5-cli`](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-cli) and NPM to manage my project.

Every time I want to run my project, I type the command `ui5 serve -o index.html` to start the service. And in my browser, I have to visit `localhost:8080/index.html` to get my project view.

But if I just type `localhost:8080/`, it cannot find `index.html` automatically. So how to resolve the problem?

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ui5 serve -o index.html",
    "build": "ui5 build --all"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "keyword"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@openui5/sap.m": "^1.64.0",
    "@openui5/sap.ui.core": "^1.64.0",
    "@openui5/sap.ui.layout": "^1.64.0",
    "@openui5/sap.ui.unified": "^1.64.0",
    "@openui5/themelib_sap_belize": "^1.64.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the simple `ui5.yaml` generate by `ui5 init` command:

```
specVersion: '1.0'
metadata:
  name: appname
type: application
```

So how to just visit `localhost:8080` in browser and it can get to my project?